# Spring Boot app consuming Ceph Swift API via JOSS Swift Client

Tags: spring-boot, openstack-swift, ceph

I am very new to Ceph and not yet very seasoned with Spring Boot Java application development either. I have set up a Ceph Object Storage cluster with Swift Object Gateway. 
Now I have a Spring Boot app and I need to get/post/delete objects from my Ceph storage via this Swift Object Gateway. I am trying to use the JOSS Swift Client, but I just can't figure out how I can use it to expose the Ceph objects as JSON for my frontend (Vue.js).

Can anyone in here please point me into the right direction how to set this up properly? I know I need to create a model, a service and a controller, but I just don't quite know where to start...

Thanks for helping me in advance!